# Multiple self- join query on same id group by distinct id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

| sku | product | Qty | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3M TAPE | 1 | 5.50 |
| 1 | 3M TAPE | 10 | 4.00 |
| 1 | 3M TAPE | 20 | 3.25 |
| 4 | Scotch | 10 | 6.00 |
| 4 | Scotch | 15 | 5.50 |
| 4 | Scotch | 20 | 4.75 |

I want a self-joined table that looks like this:

| sku | product | Qty_1 | Price_1 | Qty_2 | Price_2 | Qty_3 | Price_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3M TAPE | 1 | 5.50 | 10 | 4.00 | 20 | 3.25 |
| 4 | Scotch | 10 | 6.00 | 15 | 5.50 | 20 | 4.75 |

I tried a multiple self join with a group by sku but it does not have the intended result. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table testTable(sku int, product varchar(50), Qty int, Price  float);

 insert into testTable values(  1 , '3M TAPE',        1  ,     5.50 );
 insert into testTable values(  1 , '3M TAPE',       10  ,     4.00 );
 insert into testTable values(  1 , '3M TAPE',       20  ,     3.25 );
 insert into testTable values(  4 , 'Scotch',        10  ,     6.00 );
 insert into testTable values(  4 , 'Scotch',        15  ,     5.50 );
 insert into testTable values(  4 , 'Scotch',        20  ,     4.75 );
```

Query:

```
 with cte as 
 (
   select *,row_number()over(partition by sku order by null) rn from testTable
 )
 select sku,product,
 max(case when rn=1 then qty end)Qty_1,
 max(case when rn=1 then price end)Price_1, 
 max(case when rn=2 then qty end)Qty_2,
 max(case when rn=2 then price end)Price_2,
 max(case when rn=3 then qty end)Qty_3,
 max(case when rn=3 then price end)Price_3
 from cte
 group by sku, product
```

Output:

| sku | product | Qty_1 | Price_1 | Qty_2 | Price_2 | Qty_3 | Price_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3M TAPE | 1 | 5.5 | 10 | 4 | 20 | 3.25 |
| 4 | Scotch | 10 | 6 | 15 | 5.5 | 20 | 4.75 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69b043c9c0a7bbe15ee5c720cdb33d39)*